# Inline assembly in C with a jump and two return statements

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, inline-assembly

I would like to have a `void` function which prints whether carry (overflow) happened and print the value of the (possibly overflowed) summand.

This is my try, but it does want to compile:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long ulong;

void
func()
{
    ulong a = 3;
    ulong b = 1;
    ulong c;

    __asm__(
            "\taddq\t%2, %q0\n"     /* Add b to a and store in c */
            "\tjc\tcarry"
            : "=r" (c)              /* Outputs */
            : "0" (a), "rme" (b)    /* Inputs */
            );
    printf("no carry\nc = %lu\n", c);
    return;
    __asm__("carry:");
    printf("carry\nc = %lu\n", c);
    return;
}

int
main()
{
    func();
}
```

However, it runs when I remove the first `return` statement, but then it prints twice if no carry happened.

How can I do this with two return statements?

Comment: You are aware this can be easily done in pure C, right?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this, but I don't know if I can be so sure that it generates the same code (I'm really not interested in this particular example, but I am in need of something similar for low-level multiprecision arithmetics).

Comment: For gcc, clang, and intel's compiler you can use `__builtin_uadd_overflow` to do the add and it returns the overflow flag ex: `if (__builtin_uadd_overflow(a, b, &c) {//overflowed}` You can find a list of functions [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html)

Comment: I cannot assume that people have one of the more recent GCC's. But I will keep this in mind, thanks!

Comment: @aahlback Also consider using `setc` instead of a jump.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`asm goto`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#GotoLabels) for that. To do that, add `goto` after `__asm__`, change your label to be a C label, pass the label after the clobbers, and then use a `%l` to refer to it. Here's your program with those fixes applied:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned long ulong;

void
func()
{
    ulong a = 3;
    ulong b = 1;
    ulong c;

    __asm__ goto(
            "\taddq\t%2, %q0\n"     /* Add b to a and store in c */
            "\tjc\t%l[carry]"
            : "=r" (c)              /* Outputs */
            : "0" (a), "rme" (b)    /* Inputs */
            :
            : carry
            );
    printf("no carry\nc = %lu\n", c);
    return;
    carry:
    printf("carry\nc = %lu\n", c);
    return;
}

int
main()
{
    func();
}
```

Though as was mentioned in the comments, for this use case in particular, you should just use `__builtin_uaddl_overflow` instead, unless your goal is just to learn how to jump out of inline assembly.